# Python Pandas: How to remove list brackets from data frame when exporting to CSV when using a dict?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am trying to save a converted dict to dataframe to a csv like so:

I am using raspberry pi 4

```py
data = {'col_1': [1], 'col_2': [2]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).to_csv("file.csv")
```

But my dict has scalar values, thus I convert them to a list so that they will have an index. Doing so results in the following csv output

```
col_1, col_2
[1], [2]
```

But I want

```
col_1, col_2
1, 2
```

How do I remove the '[' ']' from the csv?

One solution is to use file/replace command in excel, but I wanted to do this within python.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried this and get the same result

Comment: in both cases i get your expected output actually doesnt seem to care about from_dict or not ... I do not get your described output I get your expected output

Comment: dear friend, please check your pandas/python version, as per your input, it should give the results that you expecting. I tried it and confirmed it.

Comment: I am using raspberry pi 4 would that matter? When using scalar value I get an exception thus I put my values in brackets [1] [2] but those brackets stay on the outputted csv file.

Comment: The hardware you're using doesn't matter much, but the version of Pandas surely matters. What version are you using? (type `pip show pandas` or `print(pd.__version__)`)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data = {'col_1': [1], 'col_2': [2]}

keys = str(list(data.keys()))
values = str(list(data.values()))

ch = "[]'"
for char in ch:
    keys = keys.replace(char,'')
    values = values.replace(char,'')

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(keys+'\n')
    f.write(values)
```

## Output:

```
col_1, col_2
1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is already working, there is no bracket:

```
import io
text = io.StringIO()

data = {'col_1': [1], 'col_2': [2]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).to_csv(text)

print(text.getvalue())
```

output:

```
,col_1,col_2
0,1,2
```